# how to generate radom numbers using seed to avoid new result

Tags: python, random

I need to generate random 3D coordinates, so that every run has new random points. I am trying to add seed to avoid having same points every time.

So far I have tried this

```
from random import *
rnd = random.Random(8)
x,y,z = 7.045,23.569,63.447

x1,y1,z1 = (rnd.uniform(x-3.5,x+3.5),rnd.uniform(y-3.5,y+3.5),rnd.uniform(z-3.5,z+3.5))
newcord = [x1,y1,z1]
print newcord
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use random.seed function?

Answer (score 2):

Change the second line `rnd = random.Random(8)` to `rnd = Random()`. Otherwise it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

To set the seed using your existing code:

```
import random as rnd
rnd.seed(8)
x,y,z = 7.045,23.569,63.447
newcord = [rnd.uniform(x-3.5,x+3.5),rnd.uniform(y-3.5,y+3.5),rnd.uniform(z-3.5,z+3.5)]
print newcord
```

Using the seed means each time you run the code you will get the same random numbers. This way your results are reproducible.